# Why do I need these symbols to run a program?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("Goodbye, World!");
  return 0;
}
```

Why do I need `#`,`<>`, `.h`, and `()`?

What are their purposes?

Comment: Is this your computer's suicide note?

Answer (score 6):

`#` means its a command for the preprocessor. C programs are run through a preprocessor before they are compiled. In this case, the preprocessor is going to include `stdio.h` file.

`<>` specifies the type of include the preprocessor will do. You can also use `""` here. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename for a discussion of the differences.

`.h` is part of the name of the file. The file's name is `stdio.h`. The portion after the `.` in a filename is called the extension, and typically is used to indicate the type of the file. In this case `.h` stands for header.

`()` is used to indicate that you are calling a function. Otherwise given `printf` and `"Goodbye World"`, how is the compiler supposed to know what you wanted to do? Did you want to add them? multiply them?

Answer (score -2):

This is called *syntax* of the language. It is similar to why English is written the way it is with its requirement of a subject and predicate for sentences.

However, nowhere do I see your symbols used except the *parentheses*, which contain parameters for a function.

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>` has the others.

Comment: Sorry, my answer should have been a comment.